# Calculate row in GridView based off two other rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, row, cells

I have a GridView that shows the number of jobs and number of documents called XDA. In the third column called EPOD, I want to calculate this by jobs minus XDA.

GridView:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" 
                                id="gvResults" 
                                CssClass="tblResults" 
                                OnItemDataBound="gvResults_OnItemDataBound" 
                                AllowSorting="true" 
                                OnSortCommand="gvResults_Sort" 
                                DataKeyField="ID" 
                                AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                            <HeaderStyle CssClass="tblResultsHeader" />
                            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#EEEEEE" />
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="JobsDelivered" HeaderText="No. Jobs deliv" SortExpression="JobsDelivered"></asp:BoundField>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ePODXDA" HeaderText="ePOD XDA" SortExpression="ePODXDA"></asp:BoundField>
```

Code behind:

```
 protected void gvResults_OnItemDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            LookupLeagueTable main = (LookupLeagueTable)e.Row.DataItem;
            GridView gv = (GridView)sender;

        }
    }
```

So I tried using this but the code gets stuck in the foreach:

```
foreach (DataRow row in e.Row.Cells)
{
    row["EPOD"] = Convert.ToInt32(row["JobsDelivered"]) - Convert.ToInt32(row["ePODXDA"]);
}
```

I also tried `main.EPOD = main.JobsDelivered - main.ePODXDA;` but the Grid still displayed zero

Populating the grid:

```
List<LookupLeagueTable> main = LookupLeagueTable.SearchCustomerListItems(Company.Current.CompanyID,
                    SearchStrings,
                    SearchFields,
                    DateTypeKey,
                    FromDate,
                    ToDate,
                    SortExpression,
                    SortDirection);



        gvResults.DataSource = main;
        gvResults.DataBind();
```

`SearchCustomerListItems` then runs an sql statement:

```
select 
        sum(case when (select count(distinct j.ID) from job_new j where jn.ID = j.ID AND j.JobOwnerID = j.DeliverMemberID)>0 then 1 else 0 end) as JobsDelivered,
        sum(case when (select count(jds.EPODImage) from job_dockets jds where jds.jobid=jn.id )>0 then 1 else 0 end) as ePODXDA
    FROM customer c
    LEFT JOIN job_address ja ON c.AccountCode = ja.Code AND c.Company_ID = ja.Company_ID
    JOIN  AddressType jat ON ja.AddressType = jat.ID and jat.Description = 'Debtor'
    LEFT JOIN job_new jn ON ja.JobID = jn.ID
    WHERE  jn.IsActive = 1
```

Comment: how do you populate the grid ?

Comment: @Mainak I edited my question to show the code

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you could adapt. Try out this simple code may help you:

Add a template field in place of the third column:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="EPOD">
 <ItemTemplate>
  <asp:Lable runat="server" ID="lblEpod">
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Then OnRowDataBound You could calculate field as expected:

```
protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        int no_job = Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.Cells[0].Text); // as your No of Job is at 0 place of Gridview
        int XDA = Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.Cells[1].Text); 
        Lable lblEpod = e.Row.FindControl("lblEpod") as Lable;
        lblEpod.Text = Convert.ToString(no_job - XDA);
    }
}
```